# Sitemap and MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitemap

Is there a way to use a classic asp.net sitemap but configure the request routing so it calls an MVC controller and associated action?

For example:

```
<siteMap>
    <siteMapNode url="~/something.aspx" controller="Home" action="Default" />
</siteMap>
```

Therefore the url ~/something.aspx would be routed to the Default action on the Home controller.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you want to try

http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/releases/view/60377

This is good written sitemap provider for MVC

Comment: I've reviewed that already, thanks. My original question still stands in terms of loading a specific controller and action based on a request to a specific virtual URL. In the context of MVC would this be best done by a filter, routehandler, controller resolver or something else? I appreciate this is clash of two ways of doing something but I am just curious. Thanks